# C: Base 64 to binary conversion

Tags: c, base64

I've been working to implement a base64 decoder in C. I have been reading up on base64 conversion in places such as the Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) and also using online [converters](https://conv.darkbyte.ru/) to check my work. It seems straight forward: just replace every base64 character with the corresponding 6-bit binary string!

My Base64-to-binary decoding is correct as long as the base64 string to decode is a multiple of 4. If the string length is not a multiple of 4, or there are equal signs present for padding, my code does not match the results from online converters.

I thought I understood the padding -- just replace the '=' character with zeros (6, for 6 bits). However, I still don't match the converter's result when this is employed.

Here is the code I've written:

```
int main(void){

    printf("Testing b642bin ...\n\n");
    printf("Case 1: Converting 'AA==' to bin:\n");
    printf("Expected Result: 000000000000000000000000\n");
    printf("Actual Result:   %s\n\n", b642bin("AA=="));
    printf("Case 2: Converting '+aHg' to bin:\n");
    printf("Expected Result: 111110011010000111100000\n");
    printf("Actual Result:   %s\n\n", b642bin("+aHg"));
    printf("Case 3: Converting 'kNSHd94m7d+=' to bin:\n");
    printf("Expected Result: 1001000011010100100001110111011111011110001001101110110111011111\n");
    printf("Actual Result:   %s\n\n", b642bin("kNSHd94m7d+="));

    return 0;
}

char bin6_table[65][7] =   {"000000", "000001", "000010", "000011", "000100",
                        "000101","000110", "000111", "001000", "001001",
                        "001010", "001011", "001100", "001101", "001110",
                        "001111", "010000", "010001", "010010", "010011",
                        "010100", "010101", "010110", "010111", "011000",
                        "011001", "011010", "011011", "011100", "011101",
                        "011110", "011111", "100000", "100001", "100010",
                        "100011", "100100", "100101", "100110", "100111",
                        "101000", "101001", "101010", "101011", "101100",
                        "101101", "101110", "101111", "110000", "110001",
                        "110010", "110011", "110100", "110101", "110110",
                        "110111", "111000", "111001", "111010", "111011",
                        "111100", "111101", "111110", "111111", "000000"};

char base64_table[65] =      {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H',
                        'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P',
                        'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X',
                        'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f',
                        'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',
                        'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v',
                        'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3',
                        '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '+', '/','='};

char* b64Char2bin(char b64){

    int n = 64;
    int k;
    char *bin;

    for(k=0;k<n;k++){
        if (b64 == base64_table[k]) {
            bin = bin6_table[k];
            break;  
        }
    }
    return bin;
}

char* b642bin(char *b64_str) {

    int i;
    size_t len = strlen(b64_str);

    char* bin_str = (char*)malloc(((len * 6) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    for (i = 0; i < (int)len; i++) {
      const char* binSextet = b64Char2bin(b64_str[i]);
      memcpy(&bin_str[6*i], binSextet,7);
    }

    return bin_str;
}
```

The output looks like this:

Testing b642bin ...

```
Case 1: Converting 'AA==' to bin:
Expected Result: 000000000000000000000000
Actual Result:   000000000000000000000000

Case 2: Converting '+aHg' to bin:
Expected Result: 111110011010000111100000
Actual Result:   111110011010000111100000

Case 3: Converting 'kNSHd94m7d+=' to bin:
Expected Result: 1001000011010100100001110111011111011110001001101110110111011111
Actual Result:   100100001101010010000111011101111101111000100110111011011101111110000000
```

If the converter I provided is correct, I don't understand Base64. Clearly you do not simply replace each character with the corresponding 6 bits of binary. Why is Case 1 and 2 correct, but Case 3 is not?

Answer (score 0):

Bytes (well, octets if you want to get all technical) are 8 bits long. Base64 encodes 6 bits at a time. Padding is used when the number of bytes that were encoded *isn't* a multiple of three, therefore the number of bits *isn't* a multiple of six. When decoding base64 with padding, you don't output *more* zero bits, you output *less* bits to produce the correct number of bytes.

As a concrete example:

Base64: `////`
Binary: `11111111 11111111 11111111`

Base64: `//8=`
Binary: `11111111 11111111`

Base64: `/w==`
Binary: `11111111`

Comment: Each case you provided makes sense. Could you please explain Case 3 in my example? The first 10 Base64 chars perfectly encode 10*6 bits = 60 bits, which is still 4 bits shy of 8 bytes, so I understand we need 4 more bits. However, the 11th Base64 character, '+', is given in binary as '111110' - 5 bits without 0's - it seems we need 65 bits to encode this string. Can you explain this? What would the conversion look like for kNSHd94m7d+= vs. kNSHd94m7d8= and why?

Comment: @Matt a correct Base64 encoder won't produce `kNSHd94m7d+=`. A strict decoder would reject it as invalid; a forgiving one would decode it the same as `kNSHd94m7d8=`.

Comment: (only `A`, `Q`, `g`, or `w` should precede `==`, and only `A`, `E`, `I`, `M`, `Q`, `U`, `Y`, `c`, `g`, `k`, `o`, `s`, `w`, `0`, `4`, or `8` should precede `=` in correct Base64.)

Comment: Okay, that's helpful. So I suppose the guiding principle to Base64 to binary decoding is to ensure that the output is divisible by 8 -- it can only output raw bytes. Further, if the last character to decode would result in more or less than this condition, trailing zeroes are removed (or added) until the condition is fulfilled. If, however, there are no trailing zeroes and the 'extra' bits are 1, this is deemed invalid decoding so the program should either halt (strict decoder) or truncate the ones until the first condition is satisfied (forgiving decoder). Could you confirm and/or expand?

Comment: @matt Looks like you've got it. If you look at it as a transform between groups of 3 bytes and groups of 4 base64 characters it's as clear as can be. If the last group is 3 bytes then everything is normal. If the last group is 1 or 2 bytes, then an encoder outputs a character with some low 0 bits that don't correspond to any bits in the input, followed by 2 or 1 `=` symbols — and a decoder reverses that process.